# ASP.NET Core Web App Error: Some services are not able to be constructed

Tags: c#, .net-core, redis, web-applications, e-commerce

This is my first question in StackOverFlow

Now, I'm using asp.net core 5.0 and I am trying to create database for Redis called Basket. But I encountered an Error.

This is the Error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Core.Interfaces.IBasketRepository Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Infrastructure.Data.BasketRepository': Unable to resolve service for type 'StackExchange.Redis.IConnectionMultiplexer' while attempting to activate 'Infrastructure.Data.BasketRepository'.)
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Core.Interfaces.IBasketRepository Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Infrastructure.Data.BasketRepository': Unable to resolve service for type 'StackExchange.Redis.IConnectionMultiplexer' while attempting to activate 'Infrastructure.Data.BasketRepository'.
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'StackExchange.Redis.IConnectionMultiplexer' while attempting to activate 'Infrastructure.Data.BasketRepository'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache lifetime, Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, Int32 slot)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite(ServiceDescriptor serviceDescriptor, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)     
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)     
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(IEnumerable`1 serviceDescriptors, IServiceProviderEngine engine, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(IEnumerable`1 serviceDescriptors, IServiceProviderEngine engine, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection services, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DefaultServiceProviderFactory.CreateServiceProvider(IServiceCollection containerBuilder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.ServiceFactoryAdapter`1.CreateServiceProvider(Object containerBuilder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at API.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\projects\angular\Ecommerce\API\Program.cs:line 16
   at API.Program.<Main>(String[] args)
watch : Exited with error code -532462766
watch : Waiting for a file to change before restarting dotnet...
```

Basket Repository

```
namespace Infrastructure.Data
{
    public class BasketRepository : IBasketRepository
    {
    
    private readonly IDatabase _database;
    public BasketRepository(IConnectionMultiplexer redis)
    {
        _database = redis.GetDatabase();
    }
    

    public async Task<bool> DeleteBasketAsync(string basketId)
    {
        return await _database.KeyDeleteAsync(basketId);
    }

    public async Task<CustomerBasket> GetBasketAsync(string basketId)
    {
        var data = await _database.StringGetAsync(basketId);

        return data.IsNullOrEmpty ? null : JsonSerializer.Deserialize<CustomerBasket>(data);
    }

    public async Task<CustomerBasket> UpdateBasketAsync(CustomerBasket basket)
    {
        var created = await _database.StringSetAsync(basket.Id, JsonSerializer.Serialize(basket), 
            TimeSpan.FromDays(30));

        if (!created) return null;

        return await GetBasketAsync(basket.Id);
    }
}
```

}

This is my ApplicationServicesExtensions Class

```
public static class ApplicationServicesExtensions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddApplicationServices(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IBasketRepository, BasketRepository>();
            services.AddScoped(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), (typeof(GenericRepository<>)));

            services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = actionContext =>
                {
                    var errors = actionContext.ModelState
                        .Where(e => e.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
                        .SelectMany(x => x.Value.Errors)
                        .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage).ToArray();

                    var errorResponse = new ApiValidationErrorResponse
                    {
                        Errors = errors
                    };

                    return new BadRequestObjectResult(errorResponse);
                };
            });

            return services;
        }
    }
```

I added the following method inside the startup class

```
services.AddSingleton<ConnectionMultiplexer>(c => {
                var configuration = ConfigurationOptions.Parse(_config.GetConnectionString("Redis"), true);
                return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(configuration);
            });
```

Most likely problem is in the constructor but How can I fix this problem? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You must register interface `IConnectionMultiplexer` after that, you can inject into your repository class
replace this line to your startup class

```
services.AddSingleton<IConnectionMultiplexer ,ConnectionMultiplexer>(c => {
                var configuration = ConfigurationOptions.Parse(_config.GetConnectionString("Redis"), true);
                return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(configuration);
            });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Have a nice day.